# CLLocation to notify on entry within a radius

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm building an app that I want:

- The user sets a list of 5 friends from his contact list - Done.
- The user sets a radius - Done (for example - 1km from the user's house) - Done.
- The app fetches the friends addresses (and the latitude-longtitude) the insert them into an NSMutableArray - Done.

Now, I want that *if the users are passing one of his friends' houses (about 100m from the friend's house) within the radius*, the app will notify him that he close to the friend's house.

But if the user sets the radius to be 1km from his own house, for example, and he is passing a friend's house that the distance between his own house to the friend's house is 2km the app won't notify him.

How can I do that?

Comment: I do not understand you distance restriction in the last paragraph. In general what you are looking for is `geofencing`: http://www.raywenderlich.com/95014/geofencing-ios-swift

Comment: @luk2302 I found this tutorial, but how can I set that the notification will be sent just if the user is within 1km radius from his own house + he is about 100m from his friend's house?